# Is it possible to access a GPU remotely (i.e., from another machine)?

Tags: gpu, cloud-computing

I want to access a GPU on a computer remotely, and share this GPU with different desktops. I envision this sort of access as being similar to using a VNC. Is it possible to do something like what I've just described, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: I want to know is graphics card can shared with many computers or not by using gpu clouding? If yes, is that possible let each computer has independent desktop? Thank you~

Comment: What do you mean by many computers sharing a single graphics card?  Only the "host computer" can directly issue OpenCL or CUDA kernels to a GPU, neither of these protocols are designed to run over networks.

Comment: I want to login to one server with different desktop and not sharing the same mouse cursor and could open different 3D apps.

Comment: sam, I couldn't understand your question. Based on Aron's edits and your comments, I've attempted to pose the question in a clearer manner. I also think that the question, as asked, is off-topic for this site because it is not apparent how it relates to scientific computing, and I feel that you might get a better answer at a site like SuperUser.SE, ServerFault.SE, or even possibly Stack Overflow. Please let me know if my edits preserve the intent of your question, and I will talk to mods on the other sites to see if it is a good candidate for migration.

Answer (score 2):

VirtualGL/TurboVNC may help https://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualgl/. I haven't tried 3 VNC sessions at once but I think it should work. There are cloud solutions coming but are proprietory and you will have pay for them, it requires the hardware to handle sharing.

http://www.gputechconf.com/gtcnew/on-demand-gtc.php has some presentations on the tech.

Another thing that might help is rCUDA http://www.rcuda.net/

Comment: You say that you try 2 turbovnc client connect to one server. Is two client 'share the same desktop' or 'their mouse are different and could open different 3D apps that's what I want'?

Comment: VirtualGL allows you to access the GPU of an XServer through VNC. You run apps within the VNC session with vglrun <appname>. I know you can run multiple VNC sessions on the same node, I just don't know what happens when mutltiple sessions try to use vglrun at once. It should be easy to test (it is free), there are few configurations available, which may solve your problem http://virtualgl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/virtualgl/vgl/tags/2.3.1/doc/index.html